# Android: Main Thread blocked despite using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, ui-thread

I have a Activity that contains over 100 complex views (with images, text views etc). Showing up these views is to hard to do it without a Thread that loads the views asynchronously. So I tried to do it with an AsyncTask. I am not sure whether this is the correct way because the "hard staff" is something that HAS to be done in the UI Thread.

Now I've got the problem that the UI freezes though I used the onProgressUpdate for adding the views in the to parent view. I thought that this would result in single loading views that appear successive in the parent view. But this is not the case.

doInBackground fires all publishProgress calls and after that the main thread is blocked (activity frozen, loadbar does not rotate anymore). Is there a way to achieve what I wanted to have? I looked for solutions but alway ended up with ideas of using AsyncTask and no one had to do view-stuff as "hard staff". I am not using "get" in the AsyncTask what seems to be a problem with AsyncTask.

Here is my code for this. If you need any further information please tell me!

Is there any other way to solute this problem? Is my AsyncTask implementation not correct? I am looking for a way to load these complex views asyncronous to the parent view without blocking the main thread.

Thanks in advance!

```
public class LoadKraut extends AsyncTask<Integer,Kraut,Void> {

private Context context;
private LinearLayout parent;
private HashMap<String,HeadlineAlphabet> headlinesAlphabet = new HashMap<String, HeadlineAlphabet>();
private long time;
private Integer kategorie;
private char letter = 'X';
private int counter = 0;
private ProgressDialog dialog;


public LoadKraut(Context context) {

    /**
     * Kategorie:
     * 1 - A-Z
     * 2 - Notiz
     * 3 - Favorit
     * 4 - Giftig
     */

    Log.i("Kraut", "Start thread" + (System.currentTimeMillis()-time) + "ms");

    this.context = context;
    this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    this.time = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    dialog.setMessage("Lade Kräuter. Dieser Vorgang kann einen Moment dauern.");
    dialog.show();

}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {

    this.kategorie = params[0];

    //Create overview
    try {
        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        Dao<Kraut,Integer> dao = databaseHelper.getKrautDAO();

        parent = (LinearLayout) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.ll_conainter_sv_uebersicht_kraeuter);

        //setKraeuter(list, linearLayout, giftig)

        long test = System.currentTimeMillis();

        List<Kraut> list = new ArrayList<>();

        switch (kategorie) {

            case 1:
                list = dao.queryForAll();
                break;

            case 2:
                list = dao.queryBuilder().where().ne("notiz","").query();
                break;

            case 3:
                list = dao.queryBuilder().where().eq("favorit",true).query();
                break;

            case 4:
                list = dao.queryBuilder().where().eq("toedlichBunny",true).query();
                break;

        }

        Log.i("Kraut","Fetching duration: " + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - test));

        Iterator<Kraut> iterator = list.iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext()) {

            Kraut kraut = iterator.next();
            Log.i("Kraut","called pp for" + kraut.getName());
            publishProgress(kraut);

        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.i("Kraut", "End " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-time) + "ms");

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Kraut... value) {

    //Set all Krauts and headlines A-Z

    long test = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Kraut kraut = value[0];

    Log.i("Kraut", String.valueOf(counter));


    if((kategorie==1 || kategorie==4) && kraut.getName().charAt(0)!=letter) {
        letter = kraut.getName().charAt(0);

        HeadlineAlphabet letterHeadline = new HeadlineAlphabet(context);
        letterHeadline.setText(String.valueOf(kraut.getName().charAt(0)));
        headlinesAlphabet.put(String.valueOf(letterHeadline.getText()),letterHeadline);

        parent.addView(letterHeadline);

    }

    KrautView krautView=null;

    if(kategorie==1 || kategorie==3) {
        krautView = new KrautUebersicht(context,kategorie);
    } else if(kategorie==2) {
        krautView = new KrautUebersichtNotiz(context);
    }

    if(krautView!=null) {
        krautView.setKraut(kraut);
        parent.addView((LinearLayout) krautView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    }

    parent.getRootView().invalidate();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    counter++;

    Log.i("Kraut","Kraut View creation duration: " + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - test));

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

    if(kategorie==1) {
        //Set Alphabet Column right side
        ArrayList<String> anfangsbuchstaben = Kraut.getAnfangsbuchstaben(context);

        // Do this with an xml !
        for (int i = 1; i <= 26; i++) {

            //Log.i("Kraut", String.valueOf(i));

            String currentLetter = Helper.getCharForNumber(i);

            int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("tv_"+currentLetter.toLowerCase(),"id",context.getPackageName());
            TextView textView = (TextView) ((Activity) context).findViewById(id);

            //If no Kraut contains Letter
            if (!anfangsbuchstaben.contains(currentLetter)) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.darkgrey, context.getTheme()));
                } else {
                    textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.darkgrey));
                }
                //Make clickable to jump to A-Z Headlines
            } else {

                textView.setOnClickListener(new JumpToLetterOnClickListener(headlinesAlphabet));

            }
        }
    }

    parent.invalidate();

    if(dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "hard staff" that has to be done on the UI thread?

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `Thread.sleep()` in `onProgressUpdate()`.

Comment: "hard staff" means that I have 100 complex views that have to be added to the activity. Each views consists of 5 images that have to be set and different texts. Additional to that they use a own TextView implementation with a not standard font. I assume that this is to hard for android to load in short time.

Thanks @MikeM. I removed that and moved the Thread.sleep according to what Code-Apprentice wrote to the while-loop. I used that to give the main Thread time to update the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `onProgressView()` is called repeatedly as your `AsyncTask` runs. Therefore, it should be kept as short as possible. This also means that your current code is creating **lots** of views and adding them to the UI. Instead, you should add the view just once and then update its data in `onProgressView()`.

Also, as Mike M. states in the comments, you should not call `Thread.sleep()` in `onProgressView()` since it runs on the UI thread. This is most likely the main reason your app is freezing.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. The problem is that I **have** to create lots of views and add them to the UI. What I actually not understand is why the update that is done in `onProgressUpdate()` do not become visible after one iteration.

Comment: @Jan-PeterSchmidt You should use a ListView or RecyclerView.

Comment: @CodeApprentice thank you! That was the thing I was looking for.. Wondering why I haven't thought about this before... it is the typical usage for ListViews. I'll try it, thanks again!